# Videos.js with related carousel is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, video.js

[enter image description here][1]this is how my code is working. i need some help. I am using Video.js (http://videojs.com/) for my video gallery. I want to use the same video player as it's showing in "Funny or Die" demonstration on homepage of the videojs. This is the carousel plugin (https://github.com/funnyordie/videojs-relatedCarousel). I am not able to call that related video button and thumbnails.

```
<video id="video" src="dist/img/Video2.mp4" controls  data-setup='{"relatedcarousel":"true"}'></video>
    <script>
      videojs('video', {}, function() {
        var player = this;
         player.relatedCarousel([
         { imageSrc: 'dist/img/01.jpg', url: 'dist/img/Video2.mp4', title: 'video 1 title' },
         { imageSrc: 'dist/img/01.jpg', url: 'dist/img/Video1.mp4', title: 'video 2 title' }
        ]);
      });
    </script>
```

i want a button like this for related videos.
[enter image description here][2]
thank you

Comment: In the plugin there is no data-setup attribute and the script tags are placed after the video tags. Is that the case for you or did you put them in the `<head>`? Because if they are in `<head>` it's possible they run before the DOM is processed. Would also help if you posted details about what doesn't work exactly or the all page of code.

Comment: no that is not a problem. Problem is that it's not showing related videos button. this is the complete code for video and i called videojs & videojs-relatedCarousel in <head>